# Empty Junit reports from ant

Tags: ant, junit

I am trying to use ant to run junit tests and generate reports. 
I am able to successfully run the tests but the report files are empty.

What am I doing wrong ?

This is my build.xml :

```
<project name="JunitTest" default="test" basedir="."> 
    <property name="testdir" location="." /> 
    <property name="srcdir" location="." /> 
    <property name="full-compile" value="true" /> 
    <property name="test.reports" value="./reports" />

    <path id="classpath.base"/>
    <path id="classpath.test">

    <pathelement location="${testdir}" />
    <pathelement location="${srcdir}" />

    <path refid="classpath.base" />

    </path> 

    <target name="clean" >
        <delete verbose="${full-compile}"> 
            <fileset dir="${testdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
        </delete> `
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}" verbose="${full-compile}" >
            <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="compile">
        <junit>
            <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <test name="com.tests.nav1" />
        </junit>

        <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
            <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report todir="${test.reports}" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>

</project>
```

and this is the output on the console :

```
[junit] Using CLASSPATH C:\eclipse\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\JunitWS\SeleniumTraining\src;C:\jars\junit.jar;C:\ant\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\ant\lib\ant.jar;C:\ant\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\ant\lib\ant-junit4.jar 
[junit] Testsuite: com.tests.nav1 
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 48.187 sec 
[junit] ------------- Standard Output --------------- 
[junit] testnav2 
[junit] ------------- ---------------- --------------- 
[junitreport] Using class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison 
[junitreport] Processing C:\eclipse\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\JunitWS\SeleniumTraining\src\reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\pmahajan\AppData\Local\Temp\null236099757 
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl 
[junitreport] Transform time: 330ms 
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\pmahajan\AppData\Local\Temp\null236099757 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 49 seconds
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the ant snippet, there are a few issues:

- You have set `usefile=false`, which means no output file is created
- You have set `formatter` `type=brief`, which will print detailed information only for failed tests
- You need to also specify the `todir` - the folder where the report has to go in the `<test>` tag - the default is current folder.  This should match the folder you are using in `<junitreport>` task.

You can try with the following updated `<junit>` section...

```
    <junit>
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="com.tests.nav1" todir="${test.reports}"/>
    </junit>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   1 <target name="test" depends="compile">
   2     <junit>
   3         <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
   4         <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
   5         <test name="com.tests.nav1" />
   6     </junit>

   7     <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
   8         <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
   9             <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
   10         </fileset>
   11         <report todir="${test.reports}" />
   12     </junitreport>
   13 </target>
```

The above segment of your coded needs following changes.

1. You have to specify the to directory option in the 5th line( for example todir = ${data.reports} )
2. In the 8th line the directory specified must me data.reports.
3. The 11th line must contain the option format with the value frames (format="frames").

Answer (score 1):

The ant JUnit Task [doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) gives this example that might help you (as it apparently does exactly what you're trying to achieve):

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>

    <formatter type="plain"/>

    <test name="my.test.TestCase" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
    </test>

    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
        <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
            <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

> Runs my.test.TestCase in the same VM, ignoring the given CLASSPATH; only a warning is printed if this test fails. In addition to the plain text test results, for this test a XML result will be output to result.xml. Then, for each matching file in the directory defined for ${src.tests} a test is run in a separate VM. If a test fails, the build process is aborted. Results are collected in files named TEST-name.txt and written to ${reports.tests}.

It is specified in the doc that `printsummary` can take values `on` and `off`, but they're using `yes` in the example which is on the same page, so I guess it's accepted too.

Answer (score 0):

Please try formatter with "xml"

```
   <formatter type="${junit.format}"/>
```

where junit.format is property with appropriate value.